# Minitest IntegrationTest ArgumentError: unknown keyword: session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I implement an integration test using minitest like that

```
test "should get index" do
  get admin_product_url, params: {}, session: { user_id: @admin_user.id }
  assert_response :success
end
```

but I get this error message

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: session
```

how else can I set session information?

I am using ruby 2.4 and rails 5.0.2

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 5 is no longer possible to access session in controller tests. [Integration tests doesn't allow you to set session.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25394#issuecomment-225707180)

<sub>[`Ref`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html)</sub>

Comment: so there is no way to set session variables anymore?

Comment: @StefanSchauer I don't know any.

Answer (score 2):

Integration tests approximate a browsing session, so the requests you make can only use pass parameters, headers, etc.  From that perspective, it makes sense that the `session` accessor only becomes available once you've made an initial request and that you can't pass a Hash of session variables like this. Ideally, you should be testing more complex interactions, not just single requests, and you should be making assertions about the session values that your controller logic is setting. But you could structure the test above like this:

```
test "should get index" do
  get admin_product_url                  # first request initializes session
  session[:user_id] = @admin_user.id     # can now update session state
  get admin_product_url                  # subsequent request
  assert_response :success               # assertions follow
end
```

Comment: this solution does not work for me. I don't get the "NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass" errror but the session information is ignored

Comment: Yes, seems like @Зелёный has the right of it. The session Hash exposed to integration tests looks to be immutable. If you want to set up session state, you'll need to code the necessary preliminary requests into your test.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
test "should get index" do
  session[:user_id] = @admin_user.id
  get admin_product_url, params: {}
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: this is not working. it results in NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass